# Strong parameters in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I'm adding strong parameters to a Rails 3.2 project. It works fine with the models I want to protect. But it seems to affect other models/controllers. For example, serialization and ransack search parameter.

It seems because strong parameters changes the class of `params` from `HashWithIndifferentAccess` to `ActionController::Parameters`. I wonder if there a way (or is it a good practice) to convert `params` back so that I can use strong parameters and don't break the current code?

Comment: there are multiple ways of integrating strong parameters. ie including it per controller, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Including `include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection` in the model and defining `<model>_params` in the controller.